# Implement Virtual Scrolling on MVC3 Html Table

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to impletment virtual scrolling on the html table in MVC3? We would like to load thousands of table rows in the view but only show a chunk of the data as the user scrolls down the the page. We cannot use third party control, this must be done using jQuery 1.10.2 and asp.net MVC3? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a poor question and sounds oddly like an assignment.  Why can't you use third party libraries?  Some of them are incredibly powerful like SlickGrid.js, and reinventing that wheel just seems like a ridiculous waste of time.

Comment: classified environment, only approved software is allowed.

Comment: Well then I'd suggest looking through jqGrid.js and niceScroll.js for true virtual scrolling and building your own.  Personally, though, I think using native scrolling with a cleverly designed grid system like SlickGrid is the way to go because virtual scrolling performance just plain sucks.